# fullcalendar week date format to: 23 - 29 Sep 2012 instead of: Sep 23 - 29 2012

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Using the `titleFormat` I have:

```
$calendar.fullCalendar({
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'MMMM yyyy',                            // September 2009
        week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}", // Sep 7 - 13 2009
        day: 'dddd, MMM d, yyyy'                       // Tuesday, Sep 8, 2009
    }
```

Doc: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/titleFormat I dont understand what the `[` and `{` mean.

When I try: `d '&#8212;' d MMM [ yyyy]{[ MMM] yyyy}` it shows: **23 - 23 Sep 2012**

Comment: [] is used when the month/year/d differs in the two dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
titleFormat: {
  month: 'MMMM yyyy',
  week: "d[ MMM][ yyyy]{ '&#8212;' d MMM yyyy}",
  day: 'dddd, MMM d, yyyy'
}
```